# In collectionview Why the button tag give zero when i reload the uicollectionview objective c

Tags: objective-c, tags, uicollectionview

At the very first time when collectionview load it show tag value perfect but when i reload uicollection then the value change and some value are zero why i can't understand please help me.

```
-(void)CheckUncheckFunctionality:(id)sender event:(id)event
{

    UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;

    NSInteger subproductindex = btn.tag;
    NSLog(@"Sub:%ld",(long)subproductindex);

    if ([[arr objectAtIndex:subproductindex] isEqualToString:@"1"])
    {
        [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchacked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [arr replaceObjectAtIndex:subproductindex withObject:@"0"];
    }
    else
    {
        [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [arr replaceObjectAtIndex:subproductindex withObject:@"1"];


    }

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    CGCell *cell = [_CGCol dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CELL" forIndexPath:indexPath];

 BOOL isExist;
    isExist = [[arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"1"];

    cell.btn.tag = indexPath.row;
    [cell.btn addTarget:self action:@selector(CheckUncheckFunctionality:event:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    if (isExist) {
        [cell.btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }
    else{
        [cell.btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchacked.png"]
                            forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }


    return cell;
}

- (void) searchBar:(UISearchBar *)theSearchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {
    searching = YES;

    if([searchText length] > 0) {
        [arrgroupMember removeAllObjects];
        searching = YES;
        [self searchCollectionView];
    }
    else{
        searching = NO;
        arrgroupMember = [DatabaseAccess GetDataForMember];
    }
    [_CGCol reloadData];
}
```

on searching when collectionview gets reload d tag is set to 0.How could i preserve that

Comment: You need provide more part of code, specifically cellForItemAtIndexPath delegate

Comment: Hey i edited my code...when i search and reload datata the tag disappears and it gives 0 @dev.nikolaz

Comment: I'm checked ur code and tags should work fine. When/how u reload collection view? Did u have some changes with cell button in code maybe?

Comment: I have search bar .... When the textdidchange method fires when writing anything the collectionview get reloaded and at that time the searched item got tag 0 @dev.nikolaz

Comment: replace     CGCell *cell = [_CGCol dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CELL" forIndexPath:indexPath];
 **WITH**    CGCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CELL" forIndexPath:indexPath];

Comment: Sorry it wont work..pls Any other help would be appreciated @PKT

Comment: you are reloading collection view but not changing **arr** ?

Comment: NSLOG btn.tag after reload collection view

Comment: it shows me 0 @PKT